# Bulk update in rails with mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a scenario where I need to update some 7k records in mongodb. The query is

```
Document.all.each do |d|
d.pages_enabled_count = d.pages.where(:disabled => false).count
d.pages_enabled_to_query_count = d.pages.where(:disabled => false , :to_query => true).count
d.pages_enabled_to_rescan_count = d.pages.where(:disabled => false , :to_rescan => true).count
d.pages_enabled_to_retag_count = d.pages.where(:disabled => false , :to_retag => true).count
d.save
end
```

It looks like this query will take more than 2 hrs!! For one update it takes around 1.6 sec. What is the way to optimize this?

```
MONGODB (388.3ms) test['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"pages", "query"=>{:deleted_at=>nil, 
"document_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51cd1c435329b64899000035'), :disabled=>false}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (388.5ms) test['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"pages", "query"=>{:deleted_at=>nil, "document_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51cd1c435329b64899000035'), :disabled=>false, :to_query=>true}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (408.0ms) test['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"pages", "query"=>{:deleted_at=>nil, "document_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51cd1c435329b64899000035'), :disabled=>false, :to_rescan=>true}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (390.9ms) test['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"pages", "query"=>{:deleted_at=>nil, "document_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51cd1c435329b64899000035'), :disabled=>false, :to_retag=>true}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.9ms) test['users'].find({"owned_document_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51cd1c435329b64899000035')}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
MONGODB (0.1ms) test['documents'].update({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51cd1c435329b64899000035')}, {"$set"=>{"pages_enabled_count"=>18, "pages_enabled_to_query_count"=>0, "pages_enabled_to_rescan_count"=>0, "pages_enabled_to_retag_count"=>0, "updated_at"=>2013-08-20 04:35:47 UTC}})
```

Comment: Have you added any indexes?  If so, could you post them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
Document.all.each do |d|
  d.update({ :pages_enabled_count => d.pages.where(:disabled => false).count,
             :pages_enabled_to_query_count => d.pages.where(:disabled => false, :to_query => true).count,
             :pages_enabled_to_rescan_count => d.pages.where(:disabled => false, :to_rescan => true).count,
             :pages_enabled_to_retag_count => d.pages.where(:disabled => false, :to_retag => true).count
          })
end
```

This will speed it up a little bit because no `callbacks` or `validations` will be run.

If this is a one time activity, you could consider doing it on `Mongodb` without using `mongoid`